# No data is inserted to firebase after onChildAdded triggers

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use `firebase` in my app to post an image to `firebase storage` and also send some data to my realtime database in `firebase`.
The problem is that the image uploads successfully but no data is inserted though `onChildAdded()` event is triggered and toasts added child data !

here is my java code :

```
public void postImage(View view){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while posting is getting done !");
    progressDialog.setTitle("Posting ...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    final String title=imgTitle.getText().toString();
    final String desc=imgDesc.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title)||TextUtils.isEmpty(desc)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please input image title and image description then try again !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        try {
            final StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("PostImage").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                DatabaseReference newPost = databaseReference.push();

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            newPost.child("title").setValue(title);
                            newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc);
                            newPost.child("image").setValue(uri.toString());
                        }
                    });
                    newPost.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "The Image Uploaded successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and my firebase database rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

the point is that if I connect my android device to some proxy server the app works fine and everything works correctly !!

what's the problem ?

Comment: where have you declared `databaseReference` ?

Comment: yes I have done it globally and set it's value in onCreate() method of my activity

Comment: please refer this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Comment: if you mean my code has problems why does it work fine when I use proxy ?!!!

Comment: @AlirezaImani You say that your Toast inside `onChildAdded` works. Good, then was is the message say `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()`? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo it shows 3 values .. first of all title value , second one description value and the third one the download url of the posted image

Comment: @AlirezaImani And let me guess, there are three separate messages, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo U are right :)

Comment: @AlirezaImani In this case, the data is added but in the wrong place. You are pushing those value three times. Check `newPost -> pushediId -> title` Is it there?

Comment: @AlexMamo the database is empty and it has no data

Comment: If your toast works for sure the data is added. Maybe you are looking in wrong place, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any value with `setValue(Object obj)` of `DatabaseReference` object.

You can add a user with `setValue()` as follows:

private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

}

Using `setValue()` in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes. However, you can still update a child without rewriting the entire object. If you want to allow users to update their profiles you could update the username as follows:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);
```

You need to set value like :

```
DatabaseReference newPost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
newPost.setValue(videoTrackBean.getPercentage())
```

OR you can set value like :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(SUB_CHILD_PATH).setValue(chat);
```

You get more information from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: it seems the problem is with network I guess . because in case of using proxy in my android device every thing is done correctly

Comment: @AlirezaImani If you have network issue then how your ImageUploading code has worked? But you do not define any setValue() anywhere.

Comment: find this in my code : newPost.child("title").setValue(title);  I have defined setValue() parameters

Comment: @AlirezaImani Then it will work perfectly and it has store one record value in firebase database.

Comment: it works fine just when I use proxy ! and it sends image to storage even with no proxy

Comment: You don't write full events over here. But you need to just define set value then its working fine in your App.

Comment: Also if you just write like  DatabaseReference newPost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    
newPost.child("title").setValue(title); in OnSuccess the also it will work for you.